# Java Runtime.exec("sleep 180 ; ...")

Tags: java, ssh

I tried to ban an ip-adress temporarly if someone tryes to not join over the proxy to the minecraft server.

```
String st = e.getRealAddress() + "";
if(!st.startsWith("/x.x.x.x")) {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec("iptables -A INPUT -s " + st.replace("/","") + " -j DROP");
    runtime.exec("sleep 180 ; iptables -D INPUT -s " + st.replace("/","") + " -j DROP");
}
```

But for some reason to only executes the -A command and after I've waited three minutes I wasn't able to connect. What did I have done wrong?

Comment: Runtime.exec is does not launch a shell, you can't give it shell syntax commands like 'sleep 180; etc'.

Comment: But why does it output the first command?

Comment: because the first command is just that, one command. in the second one, you're giving it two commands and expecting shell like behaviour. Runtime exec is not a shell and it takes one command at a time. Just use Thread.sleep for the sleep.

Comment: Before you start executing external commands with Java, make sure to thoroughly read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can:

- decompose yourself the orders in java: iptables , wait, sleep,  iptables, ...
- then you must wait first iptables to finish:

use waitFor :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command iptables");
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: But if the minecraft server restarts, then it would execute the command or not?

Comment: It is not very clear: it can execute it, depends on where you put these lines.

Comment: If the minecraftserver restarts it exits every tunning jar file of the server. So I don't think that it will work bit I can try.